# Properties of invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Show that if $A$, $B$, and $A + B$ are invertible matrices with the same size, then
>   $A(A^{-1}+B^{-1})B(A+B)^{-1}=I$
>
> What does the result in the first part tell you about the matrix $(A^{-1}+B^{-1})$?

I get the first part. Help me with the second part.

Comment: I would say that it is invertible and its inverse is.....

Comment: The book's answer is that $(A+B)^{-1}$ is not equal to $(A^{-1}+B^{-1})$. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Multiply at the left by $A^-1$ and at the right first by $(A+B)$ and then by $B^{-1}$....

Comment: I believe there is a mistake here :
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836066/how-to-show-that-if-a-b-and-a-b-are-invertible-matrices-with-the-same-si?lq=1
The answerer made a mistake in the order of operations.

Answer (score 5):

It tells $A^{-1}+B^{-1}$ is invertible and its inverse is $B(A+B)^{-1}A$.

Answer (score 0):

For two $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ we find the relation $(A+B) = A(A^{-1}+B^{-1})B$ (since $(A+B)(A+B)^{-1} = I_n$). It is given that $A$ and $B$ are invertible so first premultiply this relation with $A^{-1}$ and then post multiply with $B^{-1}$ to arrive at an expression for $(A^{-1} + B^{-1})$.